# Add dropdown or select date option in Alert dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have a fairly simple question.I would like to add a dropdown option or a date chooser dialog to my application.

In the place where `Test 2?` is. Is it possible to add a dropdown into the Alert dialog?

It is the first time that I'm programming in Java.

Something like this :

[image]

Here is the code:

```
private void addNew() {
    //Invoerveld voor het invoeren van een nieuwe taak.
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Nieuwe taak");
    alert.setMessage("Which task has to be done?") ;
    alert.setMessage("Test2?");


    final EditText input = new EditText(this);      input.setEnabled(true);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Opslaan", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String description = input.getText().toString();
            task_list_adapter.addTask(description);
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Annuleer", null);

    alert.show();
}
```

Here my current pop-up window:

[image: Link to image of my pop-up window]

I would be amazingly happy If you could help me how to create a dropdown. No functions are necessary. It's just that I need to display the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You already are creating a custom view and setting it to your dialog, so I'd say you're halfway through. You just need to use a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html), adding the month names you need, or even better using a [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) to your layout.

If the sole purpose of your dialog is enabling the user to select a data, I'd suggest going with the available [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html). This [reference page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) has a lot of information on how to proceed.